# Creating a cache layer for images

Tags: php, caching

I am working on a PHP web application in which I have to introduce a cache layer over my database.

Specifically to store images in the cache layer taken from the db, the images are large in size: 4-8 MP. What would be the best way to do this? What data sources should I use?

Comment: what is a "cache layer" ?

Comment: I mean adding caching to the data access layer

Comment: Just store them in filesystem originally. In that case you don't need any caching layer

Comment: that will increase the application size exponentially

Comment: You think that storing images in DB not increasing size of your project?

Comment: It's also keeping track of changes

Comment: DB within DBMS is not a FileSystem. I do not see a reason why it should be used that way. I suggest to discard idea of storing images as binary within DB.

Comment: currently how do you structure your urls to get to a db embedded image, are you using rewrites or just get parameters?

Comment: I am using a script to get the images from the database as a string and then I re-size the image or just show it

Comment: so what do the urls look like when one requests one of these resized images ... I'm trying to formulate a cache key that would make sense for your problem space.

Comment: the image urls have the script url with the appropriate parameters like generate.php?width=xyz&id=abc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion for a scheme:

Create three folders - thumbnails, display images and original images. In these you'll store cached versions of thumbnails, resized versions for web display, and your original image.

When an image is uploaded assign it a unique name in your file system and store it there. Store the original name and the unique name in your database, along with any other pertinent information.

Assuming you have some sort of image browser to select from these images...

Retrieve image data from the database. Use that to locate thumbnails, display versions or originals.

When an image is browsed look for an existing thumbnail. If you have one, send it. If you don't, create one, store it in your thumbnails folder, and send it.

When an image is enlarged for display in the browser, check for a display version, etc. as for thumbnails. Use a resized version for display since 4-8Mp is a lot of data to send just for a web browser.

When an image is selected for download, send the original.

You need to be careful with cache-control in all this - PHP output won't automatically be cached, so you need to add the headers yourself. Doing this properly can dramatically speed up your application.

You can play with this to add sub folders if that's justified, adjust the size of your cached resized images, etc.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First of all as suggested by everyone storing images in DB is not a good idea... I think here by "Caching Layer" you mean  not to fire a query to database if image is already present in filesystem.. if thats the case ...

Keep all the final images which you have created from using script in a directory. Then use a rewrite rule which serves the image if present, otherwise pass off the creation to PHP.

More explanation..

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?719010-PHP-image-caching-in-server

Answer (score 0):

First off designate a directory for your cache to live in ... this should be writable by the web server.

Then map your request parameters to a filename in that directory.

```
$filename = $_GET["id"]."_".$_GET["width"].".jpg";
```

Then you will basically follow this pattern.

```
if (!file_exists($cache_dir.$filename)){
     // do your db query get the image and resize it to the width and then
     // save it to $cache_dir.$filename
}

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Size: ".filesize($cache_dir.$filename));
readfile($cache_dir.$filename);
```

You may also want to add a check to see if the cache record has expired (time vs modified time) along with the file_exists check.

To manually flush something from the cache you can just delete the files from the cache directory and they will be regenerated, you may want to perform this when a database record is updated with a new file to keep the cache up to date.